# Using pkill, how can I find out how many processes matched

Tags: bash, pkill

We may not know how many processes actually died as a result of a pkill command, but is there a way to echo how many processes matched?

```
pkill -f "bin/ql_node_server"
```

is there a switch to pkill that will echo how many processes matched?

on MacOS, if I use the -c option with pkill, I get:

```
pkill: illegal option -- c
usage: pkill [-signal] [-ILfilnovx] [-F pidfile] [-G gid]
             [-P ppid] [-U uid] [-g pgrp]
             [-t tty] [-u euid] pattern ...
```

Comment: You can use `pgrep` before killing them.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: You may want to use killall instead, which has more options. pkill can be used but with scripting involved. Like so: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/pkill-verbose-4175421520/

Comment: @Barmar, idk, bash coding seems like programming to me :)

Comment: We have a useful answer to the OP

Comment: I generally consider one-line commands like this to be questions about using Unix interactively, not coding.

Comment: @Barmar I hear ya, SO has more eyeballs than unix.stackexchange it seems, so I tend to get good answers here too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -c flag.

From man pkill:

> **-c, --count**
>   Suppress normal output; 
>   instead print a count of matching processes. 
>   When count does not match anything, e.g. returns zero, the command will return non-zero value.

Comment: I knew there had to be something like that, thanks for being less lazy that me in looking it up

Comment: My version only allows this option with `pgrep`, not `pkill`. Maybe it's version-dependent. I have `pkill from procps-ng 3.3.3`

Comment: yeah the -c option does not work on bashv3 on MacOS, as I indicated in the OP